# How to prevent GNOME terminal from setting `all_proxy` (and friends) environment variables

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, the GNOME Terminal would set `all_proxy` and friends as environment variables, automatically from system network settings, as configured for proxy.

However, I would like to do that manually / on-demand, for interactive shell commands in terminal windows, while the system network settings for proxy needs to stay for Google Chrome.

I'm aware that `unset` any undesired environment variables in my `.bashrc` (or similar for other shells) can workaround it. But I want to tell GNOME Terminal to not do it in the first place. Though its settings doesn't provide such an option in the GUI.

Is there hidden settings for this?

If no, where (which bug tracker site) is appropriate to request such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to change this behavior of GNOME Terminal via configs.

Your feature request has already been brought up and rejected at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747800. You can read the reasons there, which of course you may or may not agree with.

It's unlikely that requesting it again would change the developer's mind. `unset` from `.bashrc`, or patching your GNOME Terminal for yourself, are probably better options for you than trying to convince the devs, but who knows.

Let's take a step backwards. What is your reason that you want to have different settings across your apps? Especially with the boundary being exactly between graphical vs. terminal-based apps?

You say it's "interactive shell command**s** in terminal windows" (emphasis by me) versus "Google Chrome". You mentioned 1 app where you want to have these proxy settings, and refer to multiple apps (by using plural form) where you don't. Maybe turn the story inside out? Let your GNOME-wide settings follow what the majority of your apps require, and have a wrapper in front of the minority (i.e. Chrome)? Might not be the best solution for you, but definitely an option to consider.

Comment: Great advices, well taken!

And some ranting:

Google Chrome routinely/frequently updates itself, hacking it my own way was quite unstable and annoying.

GNOME Terminal would set socks proxy url with just `socks://` schema, but modern Python pieces (e.g. `request` library) would insist any of `socks5h://` `socks5://` `socks4://` `socks4a://` but not the vague `socks://`. And actually I'd like to use different minor/feature versions of socks, as well `http://` proxy urls, for different cmdl tools per their takes, beyond situations that direct connection preferred.